# Returning a concatenated string of property values for multiple nodes using XPath

Tags: c, xpath, libxml2

I'm working on a C project using libxml2.

I keep an XML document of the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<rootnode version="1.0">
    <rootchild attribute1="a" attribute2="12345678" />
    <rootchild attribute1="b" attribute2="ABCDEFGH" />
</rootnode>
```

I'd like to get a string of concatenated attribute2 values with a comma as delimiter, so for the example above the string would be: `"12345678,ABCDEFGH"`

I'd like to get as close to that string as possible using XPath. So far the best I can do is get the nodes using the following expression: `/rootnode/rootchild/attribute::attribute2`

Wrapping the above with a `string()` seems to return only the first attribute2 value.

1. Is it possible to get more than one attribute2 value using a `string()` function?
2. Is it possible to concatenate several values separated by a delimiter using XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath 2.0 you could use `/rootnode/rootchild/attribute::attribute2/string()` to get a sequence of string values or `string-join(/rootnode/rootchild/attribute::attribute2, ',')` to a single string but libxml2 does only support XPath 1.0 so you will need to evaluate `/rootnode/rootchild/attribute::attribute2` and then take the string value of each attribute and concatenate the values in your host language (C).